# Deploying an ADF taskform on Fusion instance

Tags: bpel, fusion

I am looking for the steps to deploy an ADF task form to Fusion instance. It is not possible to deploy directly from Jdeveloper (we are not allowed to create a Weblogic server connection in Jdev). Please give me the steps to deploy via ear/war file. 
The ADF taskform itself is created through the 'Auto-generate task form' option while defining  a human task in BPEL.

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps here from section 8.3 onwards. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18476_01/doc.220/e18479/deploy.htm

Assuming you have the ear/war and a weblogic server available it is very simple:

- Login to admin console
- Click the Lock & Edit button
- Click on Deployments link
- Click Install button
- Choose the ear file
- Choose target server(s)
- Follow the next screens
- Go back to the deployments link, check the box next to your new deployment, click Start button

Comment: Thank you. Is there any difference between deploying a standalone ADF application and a workflow task form ? I was able to deploy as you suggested but the task form does not open when the workflow notification (from human workflow) is clicked in the instance. Just asking to be sure.